# Nice GUI for the sudoku solver in Java

Tags: java, swing, gui, sudoku

I have implemented a GUI for my sudoku solver:

[image: Sudoku solver]

You can use mouse for operating it, yet I have coded moving the cell cursor with keys `wW/aA/sS/dD`.

My code follows:

**SudokuGrid.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.sudoku;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

/**
 * This class implements a visual component representing a sudoku board.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Feb 26, 2016)
 */
final class SudokuGrid extends JPanel {

    private static final Font FONT = new Font("Verdana", 
                                              Font.CENTER_BASELINE, 
                                              20);

    private final JTextField[][] grid;
    private final Map<JTextField, Point> mapFieldToCoordinates = 
            new HashMap<>();

    private final int dimension;
    private final JPanel gridPanel;
    private final JPanel buttonPanel;
    private final JButton solveButton;
    private final JButton clearButton;
    private final JPanel[][] minisquarePanels;

    SudokuGrid(int dimension) {
        this.grid = new JTextField[dimension][dimension];
        this.dimension = dimension;

        for (int y = 0; y < dimension; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < dimension; ++x) {
                JTextField field = new JTextField();
                field.addKeyListener(new SudokuCellKeyListener(this));
                mapFieldToCoordinates.put(field, new Point(x, y));
                grid[y][x] = field;
            }
        }

        this.gridPanel   = new JPanel();
        this.buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1);
        Dimension fieldDimension = new Dimension(30, 30);

        for (int y = 0; y < dimension; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < dimension; ++x) {
                JTextField field = grid[y][x];
                field.setBorder(border);
                field.setFont(FONT);
                field.setPreferredSize(fieldDimension);
            }
        }

        int minisquareDimension = (int) Math.sqrt(dimension);
        this.gridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(minisquareDimension,
                                                minisquareDimension));

        this.minisquarePanels = new JPanel[minisquareDimension]
                                          [minisquareDimension];

        Border minisquareBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1);

        for (int y = 0; y < minisquareDimension; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < minisquareDimension; ++x) {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(minisquareDimension,
                                               minisquareDimension));
                panel.setBorder(minisquareBorder);
                minisquarePanels[y][x] = panel;
                gridPanel.add(panel);
            }
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < dimension; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < dimension; ++x) {
                int minisquareX = x / minisquareDimension;
                int minisquareY = y / minisquareDimension;

                minisquarePanels[minisquareY][minisquareX].add(grid[y][x]);
            }
        }

        this.gridPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 
                                                                2));
        this.clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
        this.solveButton = new JButton("Solve");

        this.buttonPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.buttonPanel.add(clearButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.buttonPanel.add(solveButton, BorderLayout.EAST);

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(gridPanel,   BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);  

        clearButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            clearAll();
        });

        solveButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            solve();
        });
    }

    public void openFile(File file) {
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            clearAll();

            int cells = dimension * dimension;
            int y = 0;
            int x = 0;

            while (cells > 0) {
                if (scanner.hasNext()) {
                    String text = scanner.next();

                    try {
                        int number = Integer.parseInt(text);

                        if (number > 0 && number <= dimension) {
                            grid[y][x].setText(" " + number);
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {

                    }

                    ++x;

                    if (x == dimension) {
                        x = 0;
                        ++y;
                    }
                } else {
                    break;
                }

                --cells;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

        }
    }

    private void addSpace(JTextField field) {
        if (field.getText().isEmpty()) {
            field.setText(" ");
        }
    }

    void moveCursor(JTextField field, char c) {
        Point coordinates = mapFieldToCoordinates.get(field);
        field.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        switch (c) {
            case 'w':
            case 'W':

                if (coordinates.y > 0) {
                    grid[coordinates.y - 1][coordinates.x].requestFocus();
                    addSpace(grid[coordinates.y - 1][coordinates.x]);
                }

                break;

            case 'd':
            case 'D':

                if (coordinates.x < dimension - 1) {
                    grid[coordinates.y][coordinates.x + 1].requestFocus();
                    addSpace(grid[coordinates.y][coordinates.x + 1]);
                }

                break;

            case 's':
            case 'S':

                if (coordinates.y < dimension - 1) {
                    grid[coordinates.y + 1][coordinates.x].requestFocus();
                    addSpace(grid[coordinates.y + 1][coordinates.x]);
                }

                break;

            case 'a':
            case 'A':

                if (coordinates.x > 0) {
                    grid[coordinates.y][coordinates.x - 1].requestFocus();
                    addSpace(grid[coordinates.y][coordinates.x - 1]);
                }

                break;
        }
    }

    void clearAll() {
        for (JTextField[] row : grid) {
            for (JTextField field : row) {
                field.setText("");
            }
        }
    }

    void solve() {
        Sudoku sudoku = new Sudoku(dimension);

        for (int y = 0; y < dimension; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < dimension; ++x) {
                String text = grid[y][x].getText();

                int number = -1;

                try {
                    number = Integer.parseInt(text.trim());
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {

                }

                sudoku.set(x, y, number);
            }
        }

        try {
            Sudoku solution = new SudokuSolver(dimension).solve(sudoku);
            String skip = dimension < 10 ? " " : "";

            for (int y = 0; y < dimension; ++y) {
                for (int x = 0; x < dimension; ++x) {
                    grid[y][x].setText(skip + solution.get(x, y));
                }
            }  

            if (!solution.isValid()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Something gone wrong.");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, 
                                          ex.getMessage(),
                                          "Error",
                                          JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

**SudokuFrame.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.sudoku;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * This class holds and manages the main frame of the program.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Feb 27, 2016)
 */
public class SudokuFrame {

    private final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sudoku solver");
    private SudokuGrid grid;

    public SudokuFrame() {
        frame.getContentPane().add(grid = new SudokuGrid(9));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        buildMenu();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        centerView();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void buildMenu() {
        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");

        JMenuItem open   = new JMenuItem("Open");
        JMenuItem grid4  = new JMenuItem("4 times 4");
        JMenuItem grid9  = new JMenuItem("9 times 9");
        JMenuItem grid16 = new JMenuItem("16 times 16");

        JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");

        fileMenu.add(open);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(grid4);
        fileMenu.add(grid9);
        fileMenu.add(grid16);
        fileMenu.addSeparator();
        fileMenu.add(about);

        bar.add(fileMenu);

        open.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            int status = chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);

            if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                grid.openFile(file);
            }
        });

        grid4.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
            frame.getContentPane().add(grid = new SudokuGrid(4));
            frame.pack();
            centerView();
        });

        grid9.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
            frame.getContentPane().add(grid = new SudokuGrid(9));
            frame.pack();
            centerView();
        });

        grid16.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
            frame.getContentPane().add(grid = new SudokuGrid(16));
            frame.pack();
            centerView();
        });

        about.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    null,
                    "By Rodion \"rodde\" Efremov. Feb 27, 2016", 
                    "About", 
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        });

        frame.setJMenuBar(bar);
    }

    private void centerView() {
        Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Dimension frameSize = frame.getSize();

        frame.setLocation((screen.width - frameSize.width) >> 1,
                          (screen.height - frameSize.height) >> 1);
    }
}
```

**SudokuCellKeyListener.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.sudoku;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 * This class implements a key listener for individual sudoku board cells.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Feb 26, 2016)
 */
class SudokuCellKeyListener implements KeyListener {

    private final SudokuGrid grid;

    SudokuCellKeyListener(SudokuGrid grid) {
        this.grid = grid;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        char c = e.getKeyChar();

        switch (c) {
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
            case 's':
            case 'S':
            case 'd':
            case 'D':
            case 'w':
            case 'W':
                e.consume();
                grid.moveCursor((JTextField) e.getSource(), c);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int keyCode = e.getExtendedKeyCode();

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP
                || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT
                || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN
                || keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            return;
        }

        JTextField field = (JTextField) e.getSource();

        if (!field.getText().isEmpty() 
                && !Character.isSpaceChar(field.getText().charAt(0))) {
            field.setText(" " + field.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

(In order to run the program, please refer to [this GitHub project](https://github.com/coderodde/SudokuSolver).)

Please, tell me anything that comes to mind (API design, compliance to MVC pattern, naming, coding conventions, performance, visual appearance, and so on).